# Replace these if/elseif statements with something cleaner

Tags: php

Okay I have been working on script for about a week now. In a game(runescape) there is content known as the citadel. What you do is on weekly basis you gather resources towards upkeep and upgrades(if any). Upkeep is the weekly cost to keep the plots of the citadel up and running or they will degrade. Each tier or level that upkeep cost will change. Upgrade is any thing you are upgrading or building(new plots). You must meet upkeep first before any resources are applied to any upgrades. Every week each player can only cap a certain amount of resources. Okay now that I got that outta of the way now to explain what I am trying to accomplish. There will be a form that passes the level of each plot to the script. So what I am doing is:

```
if($citadel = '1'){
  $wood_upkeep = "1500";
  $stone_upkeep = "0";
  $bar_upkeep = "0";
  $pbar_upkeep = "0";
  $cloth_upkeep = "0";
  $rations_upkeep = "0";
}elseif($citadel = '2'){
  $wood_upkeep = "3600";
  $stone_upkeep = "0";
  $bar_upkeep = "0";
  $pbar_upkeep = "0";
  $cloth_upkeep = "0";
  $rations_upkeep = "0";
}elseif($citadel = '3'){
  $wood_upkeep = "2975";
  $stone_upkeep = "2550";
  $bar_upkeep = "0";
  $pbar_upkeep = "0";
  $cloth_upkeep = "0";
  $rations_upkeep = "0";
}elseif($citadel = '4'){
  $wood_upkeep = "1690";
  $stone_upkeep = "1500";
  $bar_upkeep = "1500";
  $pbar_upkeep = "0";
  $cloth_upkeep = "0";
  $rations_upkeep = "0";
}elseif($citadel = '5'){
  $wood_upkeep = "2250";
  $stone_upkeep = "2300";
  $bar_upkeep = "2200";
  $pbar_upkeep = "100";
  $cloth_upkeep = "0";
  $rations_upkeep = "0";
  $cap_limit = "2000";
}elseif($citadel = '6'){
  $wood_upkeep = "2470";
  $stone_upkeep = "1495";
  $bar_upkeep = "1690";
  $pbar_upkeep = "1365";
  $cloth_upkeep = "2210";
  $rations_upkeep = "0";
  $cap_limit = "2350";
}elseif($citadel = '7'){
  $wood_upkeep = "2800";
  $stone_upkeep = "400";
  $bar_upkeep = "1600";
  $pbar_upkeep = "2000";
  $cloth_upkeep = "3000";
  $rations_upkeep = "3000";
  $cap_limit = "2700";
}
```

Times that by 10 plots that is alot of code(over 500 lines). I calculated and it would come out to over 2000 lines of code just to spit out a number of "cappers" needed to achieve x upgrade/upkeep. What these if/elseif statements are doing is simply just assigning the cost values based on what tier(lvl) x plot is. Then I use the cost values and add em all up and divide by the weekly cap limit and that will give me the number of cappers need to achieve x upgrade + upkeep. I am pretty sure there is a simpler way of doing this, just not aware of how or what.

Comment: in all honesty I'd probably want to make a function that dictates the values based on the input, but your numbers fluctually pretty wildly in a pattern I don't understand and am too tired to attempt.

Comment: not very good in programming but i think it would be better if all the data is in your database. it would be easier to maintain and modify your data. you could also set $citadel as the id so that you can get its details. Cleaner code right?

Comment: Yes because over 2000 lines of code to do one task is rediculous

Answer (score 8):

use switch-case

```
/* zeroing the values as suggested by @paul-t */

$wood_upkeep = "0";
$stone_upkeep = "0";
$bar_upkeep = "0";
$pbar_upkeep = "0";
$cloth_upkeep = "0";
$rations_upkeep = "0";

switch($citadel) {
    case '1':
        $wood_upkeep = "1500";
        break;

    case '2':
        $wood_upkeep = "3600";
        break;

    case '3':
        $wood_upkeep = "2975";
        $stone_upkeep = "2550";
        break;

    .
    .
    .

    case 'n':
        //statements here
        break;


}
```

Comment: Wow I am sooooo stupid. I totally forgot about switch statements

Comment: ...and I would add, before the switch, to set all variables to zero, and then only set what is needed within each case to save some statements.

Comment: Make sense Paul. Thx for that

Comment: Try remove the values with 0 by initializing them first and then change only if needed

Comment: @DanielJohanson: ... also, remove the variables within each case that are also set to zero.

Comment: @mrid: ... yes, that looks better, thanks for the edit(s). Upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

There are primary three solutions I've got on my mind right now:

1. Use switch (citadel) + case.
2. Prepare associative array with those values like:

   $citadelParams[1] = Array("wood_upkeep" => "3600", "stone_upkeep = "0", ...);

You can access those values simply by:

```
$citadelParams[$citadel_id]["wood_upkeep"];
```

3. This is my favourite. Just use xml or json file for storing those values and read them in your code. There is no need to hardcode values in your code, and also you can easily find and change values in this specific file even if you are not a programmer :)

Some helpful things to use with #3:

- file_get_contents to read file to string
- json_decode to parse string read before with file_get_contents (I suggest to use second parameter as TRUE, so you can get simply associative array in return and use it like in #2)

Comment: I'd say number two is the best

Comment: @DanielJohanson you just need to create a json/xml file of this data, and read it

Comment: I've added some basic functions to look onto so it would be easier to implement #3

Answer (score 1):

Personally, ( if this is for a game or such ).  I would store each of these values in their own file as an array.  almost like a config.   So you would have files like

file citadel1.php

```
<?php
return [
   'wood_upkeep' => "1500",
   'stone_upkeep' => "0",
   'bar_upkeep' => "0",
   'pbar_upkeep' => "0",
   'cloth_upkeep' => "0",
   'rations_upkeep' => "0",
];
```

Then you just load the file depending on the value of `$citadel`

```
$values = include "{$pathtofile}/citadel{$citadel}.php";
```

That way you can organize them way better.  For other things like maybe you have a folder for `citadel` with the configs in there, then you have a folder for `blacksmith` etc.  Be way easier then digging through code to find them.

```
home/
   buildings/
        citadel/
            citadel1.php
            citadel2.php
            citadel3.php
            citadel4.php
            citadel5.php
       blacksmith/
            ... etc.
```

Also say you want to make a upgrade to `$citadel = '6'` you would just copy the file for `citadel5.php`, change a few things, save it as `citadel6.php` and then set `$citadel to = 6` no code change required.

It's beautiful, no if required.

Note - assigning a var from the file like so, only works with `include`, if I recall correctly.

You can even save them using php.

```
    file_put_contents('citadel5.php', "<?php\nreturn ".var_export($values, true ).";");
```